# Google account shows unknown device logged in. Password reset and 2FA does not make this device go away

Tags: google-account

When I login to my google account and list the devices that have accessed my account, I see an unknown device access from India. I do not recognize this device and have subsequently changed my password and added two factor authentication. But I still see the same device access my google account less than 2 days ago. I added 2FA about 3 weeks back and have been regularly checking my account access for unknown devices.

[image]

Any insight into this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any Application-specific passwords created? They are specifically designed to allow a specific service that may not support 2FA to access you Google account.

Comment: No. I do not have any application specific passwords. I just checked my account.

Comment: Isn't it your (android) phone?

Comment: No. My windows computer and android phone are listed in that same list (not shown in image). I live in USA and it shows USA for the computer and my android phone. This samsung galaxy star is an outlier since I or anyone in my family do not own one and we are not in India.

Comment: on a related note - Does google have a support line that I can log this issue. I tried to search online but I could'nt find one. Apparently since its a free service google is providing, there is no customer service for it. I tried everything in their help webpage when encountering an unknown device (change password, add 2FA). I am not sure what else i could do.

Comment: [Go here](https://security.google.com/settings/u/0/security/permissions?pli=1) then click on the device and click `Revoke`.

Comment: @Trav I get the following message when I go that webpage.

`You haven't granted any apps or websites access to your Google Account.
When you allow a website or an app access to one or more of your Google products, we'll list it here. You can disable the access you've granted at any time.`

Comment: Try going to http://security.google.com and signing in. Then click on `Connected Apps and Sites`

Comment: @Ramhound - I am sorry. I did not know where else to ask. Can you please point to another forum if you know and I can delete this question here.

Comment: @Ramhound - thank you. Please delete this question here if you can. I tried searching for a delete button, but found none.

Comment: It already will automatically be closed shortly more then likely.  Only moderators or the author of a question can delete a question.  There are expections but this question wouldn't be one of those exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

From [See devices with access to your Google Account - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?p=devices&hl=en)

> ## Remove device access
>
> If you lose a device or notice any suspicious activity on it, you should remove the device’s access to your account.
>
> 1. Go to your [Devices & activity page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity).
> 2. Click on the device.
> 3. Click Remove access. If you don’t see a button to remove access, follow the steps to [secure your
>    account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount).

Answer (score -2):

This question is kinda off topic. One suggestion to get this person off is to contact Google support directly as if someone has accessed your account that is a serious issue.

From personal experience you get to flak to real people and it's super helpful!

Google account support:

[support.google.com/accounts](https://support.google.com/accounts/topic/2401957?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=3382253)